# How to reduce extra space comes at start of TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Designing custom `TextView` and I want to remove extra white space in front of text in TextView.

I tried setting `padding = 0dp` and `android:includeFontPadding="false"` but still adds some white space.

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="LorenIP Some"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:padding="0dp"    
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

Comment: Show your XML here, so we can help you.

Comment: Show a visual example of the space and how you would like it to look.

Comment: check the layout wrapping your TextView and the parent Layout if they have padding or margin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Should Use a custom  TextView and override onDraw() Method

```
    public class MyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

    private final Rect mBounds = new Rect();

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw( Canvas canvas) {
        final String text = calculateTextParams();

        final int left = mBounds.left;
        final int bottom = mBounds.bottom;
        mBounds.offset(-mBounds.left, -mBounds.top);
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
        canvas.drawText(text, -left, mBounds.bottom - bottom, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        calculateTextParams();
        setMeasuredDimension(mBounds.width() + 1, -mBounds.top + 1);
    }

    private String calculateTextParams() {
        final String text = getText().toString();
        final int textLength = text.length();
        mPaint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
        mPaint.getTextBounds(text, 0, textLength, mBounds);
        if (textLength == 0) {
            mBounds.right = mBounds.left;
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

In Xml Use This

```
<com.example.TestApp.MyTextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="LorenIP Some" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `includeFontPadding` attribute in your XML layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"/>
```

OR in JAVA:

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.idl.textview);
textView.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

Docs:

[setIncludeFontPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setIncludeFontPadding(boolean))

[includeFontPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:includeFontPadding)